# How to handle errors resulting from illegal user input with php?

Tags: php, validation

**Problem:**

On a web page an user enters a date in the form "07.02.14, 14:00". On the server, I parse the user input with the following code:

```
$myDate = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd.m.y, H:i', $_POST['userdate'] );
$mysqlDate = $myDate->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
// use $mysqlDate for SQL queries...
```

It works. But if the user enters a string that does not match the input pattern PHP terminates the script with the error

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

**Question:**

What is best practice in PHP to handle errors like these? Should I check the return value of `createFromFormat`, should I surround the whole part of the script handling with user input with a try-catch block, or is there another better solution?

**Environment:**

The script is run on a managed web server, and it's not easy for me to integrate third party libraries. So I'm looking for a best practice that works with PHP 5.3 out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

What about strtotime($_POST['userdate'])

Comment: It cannot parse the special input syntax and returns no result.

Comment: then read the user input and split it manually then create a date format from that

Answer (score 0):

A bit (too?) late but yea, in this case you could do this:

```
<?php
    $myDate = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd.m.y, H:i', $_POST['userdate'] );
    if($myDate == false){
        //Handle Validation stuff
    }

    $mysqlDate = $myDate->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
    // use $mysqlDate for SQL queries...
?>
```

This works because the method `DateTime::createFromFormat();` returns `false` on failure as per the documentation here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

**In general**, most methods in php typicaly return a `false` if an error occures